# modify post meta data remotely without xmlrpc

Tags: xml-rpc, remote

I want to make changes to post meta data from another server and had used xml-rpc.  After some security concerns were raised, I disabled xmlrpc.  I do not have remote access to the MySQL database.

I prefer to code a solution in ruby to make this all work.  Is there an approach that doesn't require xml-rpc?